# Why does `i` become a string in my loop?

Tags: javascript

Why do I have to parse `i` into a number and into a variable so that I can get `str.charAt(i+1)` to work, when `str.charAt(i-1)` works just fine?

This is for coderbyte "simple symbols" and it took me two hours to figure out that `i` was sometimes a string and sometimes a number

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
    // code goes here
    var letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var letterArray=letters.split('');
    var strArray=str.split('');
    var truth=false;
    for (var i in strArray){
        var e=parseFloat(i)+1;
        if (letterArray.indexOf(strArray[i]) > -1){        
            if ((str.charAt(i-1)==='+')&&(str.charAt(e)==='+')){
                truth = true;
            }
        } 
    }



    return truth; 

}
// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
SimpleSymbols(readline());
```

Comment: Because `i` is a character. `if (letterArray.indexOf(i) > -1){`

Comment: but why does str.charAt(i-1) work and str.charAt(i+1) does not.

Comment: coincidence? it's no question that i is a character due to the for in loop you are doing.

Comment: Why do you expect `i` be a string representing a float, if nowhere in your code is anything even remotely related to a float or its string representation?

Comment: **Don't use `for ... in` for JavaScript array traversal.**

Comment: I assumed i was a number because i is the index of the array, and goes up by the value '1' for every step we take through the array. thats kinda like math right?

Comment: Don't assume. Inspect / debug `console.log()`.

Comment: *"I assumed i was a number because i is the index of the array"* Since you are using `for...in`, you are iterating over the *property names* of the object, which are always strings. Also note that your text is really hard to read if you refer to the variable i and use the personal pronoun i. In the English language, you have to capitalize I if it is a personal pronoun.

Comment: *"`i` was sometimes a string and sometimes a number"* In your code `i` is always a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+` is overloaded for strings - it is also the concatenation operator. So for example

```
'5' + 2 // '52'
```

but `-` is not overloaded in the same way; it converts strings to numbers:

```
'5' - 2 // 3
```

Comment: thank you. that explains it very clearly

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question:

> Why does `i` become a string in my loop?

Because `for...in` iterates over the property names of the object and those are always strings. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more information. You will also find a big warning box which explains why not to use `for...in` with arrays.